# What derailleur hanger do I need for my Merida Speeder 200?

Tags: road-bike, derailleur-rear

My rear derailleur hanger on my Merida Speeder 200 (2019) is slightly bent, resulting in bad shifting across the whole range.

While I found [an explanation on how to bend the hanger back](https://www.bikeradar.com/features/how-to-straighten-a-bent-mech-hanger/) I want to buy a spare one in case I need to replace it.

However,  I found a lot of different hangers online. Which one do I need?

Answer (score 2):

I contacted Merida and they told me that I need [this hanger](https://www.merida.nl/onderdelen/achterpadden/achterpad+2311004627+%28alu+scultura-reacto-ride-cyclo+cross%29/) which has Merida product ID `2311004627`.

Some other links to the same hanger (no affiliation):

- [cicloscorredor](https://cicloscorredor.com/en/gear-hangers/8985-merida-road-8317-rear-derailleur-hanger-2787640709163.html)
- [cicliserino](https://www.cicliserino.com/prodotti/componenti/forcellini-cambio/merida-forcellino-cambio-8317-0000p-cod-2311004627/)
- [ebay](https://www.ebay.ie/itm/MERIDA-FORCELLINO-CAMBIO-8317-0000P-Cod-2311004627-/264296299795)

Answer (score 0):

This site is a very good source for identifying the hanger you need:

https://wheelsmfg.com/derailleur-hangers.html

Comment: Thanks! I did find that site at first, but [when filtering by `Merida`](https://wheelsmfg.com/derailleur-hangers.html?bike_brand=6481) I did not find anything that looked like my hanger, hence I doubted if that site had a complete collection of hangers.